# OnRotate crash for DialogFragments

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception

I have a `DialogFragment` that is shown on the screen from a background thread. When I rotate the screen, my app crashes. Below is the code:

```
public void showDialog(DialogFragment dialog) {
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  dialog.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
10-24 13:20:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(3038): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

After looking for answers on SO, and [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) article, I tried doing this:

```
public void showDialog(DialogFragment dialog) {
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.add(dialog, "dialog");
  ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

But with this, I get the following error on `ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()`

```
10-24 13:26:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3765): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Don't add your dialog to the back stack. Just call 
  dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

Comment: If i do that, I get the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` error.

Comment: when and where do you call showDialog?

Comment: I call this from a Thread which runs in the background.

Comment: @Intern if your dialog is shown succesfully and exception is thrown after rotation see my answer. By the way you can only show (dialog)fragments from UI thread. I guess you are talking about an asyncTask's onPostExecute method with "I call this from a Thread which runs in the background".

Comment: @aegean: Yes, I am calling it on the `runOnUiThread`. I will try your answer and reply with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a method as `showDialog(DialogFragment dialog)` but your problem is in your dialogFragment's initialization I guess. If you put dialogFragments initialization data to its arguments, your problem will be solved. Write a newInstance method and use it on creation of your dialog. See sample [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Edit: Reason of your exception is; your activity and also dialogFragment is destroyed and re-created somehow(maybe by config_changes not set at manifest or "settings -> developer options -> don't keep activities" is selected. This can happen, it is normal). And initialization paramaters of your dialog has been lost(became null). You have to put your initialization parameters to dialogFragment's arguments and so it can read them after re-cration on create.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
dialog.show(fm, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the fragment using a constructor with parameters?? if so that could be the case because you are not supposed to create fragments that way